# What does 弾け散る mean?

Tags: meaning

> 高温の鉄板には、垂らした水さえも弾け散る。

I looked up in a few dictionaries but I don't find the word anywhere. How come?

Answer (score 1):

散る is used with various motion verbs and forms intransitive compound verbs. As far as I can remember for now, it almost always adds the meaning of "for fragments/particles to scatter". Relatively common ones are:

- (水などが) [飛び散る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/159954/meaning/m0u/%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B3%E6%95%A3%E3%82%8B/)
- (爆発などで物が) 砕け散る
- (花びらや雪が) 舞い散る

And uncommon ones found on BCCWJ are:

- (煙が) 流れ散る
- (鳥の羽が) 羽ばたき散る

The only exception on BCCWJ was (戦場で兵士が)果て散る, where both 果てる and 散る mean "to perish" or "to die a noble death".